# How to get a record count from a joined table in a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is returning districts, and I want to get a count of the districts contacts and am not sure how to do it in my select statement

The select statement is, and I already joined the contact table,

```
select 
    dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince
from [AccountDistrictXREF] adx
    inner join [District] dist on dist.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    inner join [StateProvince] sp on sp.StateProvinceID = dist.StateID
    inner join [DistrictStateCountyXREF] dscx on dscx.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    left join [StateCounty] sc on sc.StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID
    left join [DistrictContactXREF] dcx on dcx.DistrictID = dist.DistrictID
    left join [Contact] c on c.ContactID = dcx.ContactID
where adx.AccountID = 2
```

and I am trying to do

```
select 
    dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince,
    count(c.ContactID) as "Contact Count"
from [AccountDistrictXREF] adx
    inner join [District] dist on dist.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    inner join [StateProvince] sp on sp.StateProvinceID = dist.StateID
    inner join [DistrictStateCountyXREF] dscx on dscx.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    left join [StateCounty] sc on sc.StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID
    left join [DistrictContactXREF] dcx on dcx.DistrictID = dist.DistrictID
    left join [Contact] c on c.ContactID = dcx.ContactID
where adx.AccountID = 2
```

but I get an error about aggregate function and Group by

**EDIT**

here is what the first query returns

[image: First Query]

and what I am looking for is to have a column with the amount of contacts in that district, and there may be no contacts in that district either and I need to take that into account as well

Comment: do you know which column(s) need to be included in grouping?

Comment: Post the result of first query and expected result. This can be interpreted in many ways. You need `Group by`

Comment: If you are doing a count on ContactID then you will need to Group by the other 4 in the Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want windowed `COUNT()`:

```
select 
    dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince,
    count(c.ContactID) OVER(PARTITION BY district_id) AS [Contact Count]
from [AccountDistrictXREF] adx
    inner join [District] dist on dist.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    inner join [StateProvince] sp on sp.StateProvinceID = dist.StateID
    inner join [DistrictStateCountyXREF] dscx on dscx.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    left join [StateCounty] sc on sc.StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID
    left join [DistrictContactXREF] dcx on dcx.DistrictID = dist.DistrictID
    left join [Contact] c on c.ContactID = dcx.ContactID
where adx.AccountID = 2;
```

Another option is to use `GROUP BY`:

```
select 
    dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince,
    count(c.ContactID) AS [Contact Count]
from [AccountDistrictXREF] adx
    inner join [District] dist on dist.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    inner join [StateProvince] sp on sp.StateProvinceID = dist.StateID
    inner join [DistrictStateCountyXREF] dscx on dscx.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    left join [StateCounty] sc on sc.StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID
    left join [DistrictContactXREF] dcx on dcx.DistrictID = dist.DistrictID
    left join [Contact] c on c.ContactID = dcx.ContactID
where adx.AccountID = 2
GROUP BY dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince;
```

First approach will give you every row as simple `select ... from .. join` plus count per group, second will give you aggregated values.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll mark yours as answer because you were the first to answer and showed two different ways to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the Group by error because you need to add a group by

```
select 
    dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince,
    count(c.ContactID) as "Contact Count"
from [AccountDistrictXREF] adx
    inner join [District] dist on dist.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    inner join [StateProvince] sp on sp.StateProvinceID = dist.StateID
    inner join [DistrictStateCountyXREF] dscx on dscx.DistrictID = adx.DistrictID
    left join [StateCounty] sc on sc.StateCountyID = dscx.StateCountyID
    left join [DistrictContactXREF] dcx on dcx.DistrictID = dist.DistrictID
    left join [Contact] c on c.ContactID = dcx.ContactID
where adx.AccountID = 2
GROUP BY dist.DistrictID,
    dist.DistrictName,
    sc.CountyName,
    sp.StateProvince
```

Answer (score 1):

All aggregates (sum, count, avg, min, max, etc) typically require a group by clause.  If no group by, it assumes everything is a rolled-up total and becomes one row for the result.

Also, queries with group by typically require all NON aggregate fields as part of the group by.  If you know the given field will always be the same, you can fake it by applying a MAX( field value such as district name ) to not require it as part of the group by.

```
select 
      dist.DistrictID,
      dist.DistrictName,
      sc.CountyName,
      sp.StateProvince,
      count(c.ContactID) as "Contact Count"
   from 
      AccountDistrictXREF adx
         join District dist 
            on adx.DistrictID = dist.DistrictID
            join StateProvince sp 
               on dist.StateID = sp.StateProvinceID
            left join DistrictContactXREF dcx 
               on dist.DistrictID = dcx.DistrictID
               left join Contact c 
                  on dcx.ContactID = c.ContactID
         join DistrictStateCountyXREF dscx 
            on adx.DistrictID = dscx.DistrictID
            left join StateCounty sc 
               on dscx.StateCountyID = sc.StateCountyID 
   where 
      adx.AccountID = 2
   group by
      dist.DistrictID,
      dist.DistrictName,
      sc.CountyName,
      sp.StateProvince
```

Comment: @Chris, also sql-formatting is just personal preference to see how each table hierarchically relates to its parent, and I always list the parent table.id then child table.id for the join ON condition.  Again, personal preference.